# How can I fast count how often a string appears in a given part of a sting list?

Tags: c#, list, optimization

I have a list of strings where I need to count the number of list entries that have an occurances of a specific string inside of them (and the whole thing only for a subset of the list not the whole list).

The code below works quite well BUT its performance is.....sadly not in an acceptable niveau as I need to parse through 500k to 900k list entries.For these entries I need to run the code below about 10k times (as I have 10k parts of the list I need to analyse). For that it takes 177 seconds and even more. So my question is how can I do this...fast?

```
private int ExtraktNumbers(List<string> myList, int start, int end)
{
    return myList.Where((x, index) => index >= start && index <= end 
                        && x.Contains("MYNUMBER:")).Count();
}
```

Comment: You need to use `Contains` and cannot use `StartsWith` or even `==`? How long are the strings?

Comment: Have you considered doing this in a database? Indexes would sure be of great help here. *EDIT:* Well, not when you can't use `StartsWith`.

Comment: What about regular expressions?

Comment: Sry deleted my comment was the wrong part of the code. In this special case startswith is sadly not an option (even with ordinal) as MYNUMBER can happen anywhere inside the string and I need to know only which of these strings contains that....will update the question as its not 100% clear form there.

Comment: Have you considered using full-text search engines, such as Lucene and Solr?

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov You mean instead of .contains?  from what I gathered from another question of mine (different premise) regex is slower than a startswith or a contains (in this case I only need the elements that have MYNUMBER: included).

Comment: I have tested your code ony my pc with a list that contains 1000000 strings  and it needed 555 milliseconds for 10 runs. The range was from 50000 to 100000. So either your strings are huge or your bottleneck is somewhere else.

Comment: Instead of using Linq extension methods, have you tried to see how a simple iterative solution performs? `for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)`...

Comment: @Thomas No, I mean perform regexp on full text, not for each string.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Database is sadly out of questoin there as I need to do these things in memory before I write it into the database (else I would need to read 700k entries, write them into another table, select them and then write the formated data into a third table. I fear the database admins would grill me for that one :) ). No didn't consider that so far. Not sure if local policies would allow them to be used or not.

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Nope didn't try that although I get the string as a list in a database. does that not mean I would need to join the string?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I didn't try the iterative part so far BUT I take it it would probably do the same as: MyList.GetRange(start, end).Where(x =Y x.contains("MyNumber:")),Count(); at least in essence? (just tried that one after you mentioned the iterative and that has a HUGE performance increase).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think the reason is mostly that I have 700k entries where I use the code about 10000 times (aka I check 10000 parts of the list). The time for a single one is way less. but tnx for pointing it out the quesiton is a bit unclear there.

Comment: Dammit, I got distracted. I was going to suggest a `for` loop too. But like Tim suggests, 3 minutes seems far too long just to check over a million items. I would look elsewhere for problems too, not just in this function

Comment: @Thomas : I think best place for this question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @musefan yeah I corrected the question there as it was unprecise.The 3 mins were not for 1 single check, but for a couple of thousands in a row and thus the low time sums up.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Thanks for the info will keep that in mind if I have similar problems (had overlooked that subsite of stackexchange so far).

Comment: @Thomas, actually, since you've mentioned that you're calling this method about 10k times... *that* would be the best thing to optimize. Can you first collect all the substrings you want to count in this list, and then go through the list *once*, while maintaining a counter for each substring's number of matches?

Comment: @Thomas: maybe you can calculate all ranges in one go. You just need to determine all indices of the strings which contain `MYNUMBER:` once at the beginning and store them in an `List<int>`. Then you can use this list for all range-checks.

Comment: If I understand both of you correctly I think I'm doing something similar there as I go through the list in steps of 10-1000 entries that are checked with one call (each putting the count found into the appropriate item). Never going through a specific index twice.  @TimSchmelter If that is a faster way then yes BUT wouldn't it be so that still all entries are checked for that once anyway? (thus what would the difference be performance wise to iterating from start to end then next start to end,...)?

Comment: @Thomas: you are calling the method 10000 times whereas our(?) approach just needs one call for all ranges. You need to check all occurences once, then you have all indices. Now you have still to check 1000 times but not against the whole list which contains 900k strings but only against the `List<int>` which contains less numbers. You also don't need to search the substring anymore but only to compare the index. The range check could look like: `indicesWithMyNumber.Count(i => i >= start && i <= end)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, *your* approach is a good one! If it fits Thomas, it should become the accepted answer.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko: *cough cough* I think someone has already suggested that answer, maybe you would like to upvote that :P

Comment: @musefan if you insist...

Comment: @musefan: haven't seen your answer but, yes, it looks like the idea i had. So no need to post an asnwer

Answer (score 3):

Well now we know you are calling the method 10,00 times here is my suggestion. I assume as you have hardcoded "Number:" that it means you are doing different ranges with each call? So if that's the case...

First, run an 'indexing' method and create a list of which indices are a match. Then you can easily count up the matches for the ranges you need.

NOTE: This is something quick, and you may even be able to further optimize this too:

```
List<int> matchIndex = new List<int>();

void RunIndex(List<string> myList)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        if(myList[i].Contains("MYNUMBER:"))
        {
            matchIndex.Add(i);
        }
    }
}

int CountForRange(int start, int end)
{
    return matchIndex.Count(x => x >= start && x <= end);
}
```

Then you can use like this, for example:

```
RunIndex(myList);

// I don't know what code you have here, this is just basic example.
for(int i = 0; i <= 10,000; i++)
{
    int count = CountForRange(startOfRange, endOfRange);
    // Do something with count.
}
```

---

In addition, if you have a lot of duplication in the ranges you check then you could consider caching range counts in a dictionary, but at this stage it's hard to tell if that will be worth doing anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that would work as intended? because the startofrange and endofrange is determined by the original list but matchindex has a different number of entries than them

Comment: yeah, it should do, because matchIndex knows what the indices are. For example: If it contains matches `[1, 2, 4, 7, 9]` and you want range from 4 - 9, you will get result of `3` which would be correct. Note that the `matchIndex.Count()` is not using the index of the matchIndex list, but the values stored from the original indices. Give it a try and let me know, I am very interested to know if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure a simple iterative solution will perform better:

```
private int ExtractNumbers(List<string> myList, int start, int end)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (myList[i].Contains("MYNUMBER:"))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Its always the simplest solutions one does not think about :). Currently finishing a try to measure times. If I'm not mistaken this variant should perform even better than an .GetRange and .Where combination?

Comment: Well, `GetRange()` performs a shallow copy of the elements in your range. The strings themselves shouldn't be copied, but still, it adds unneeded overhead.

Comment: `GetRange` is unnecessary, you don't want a copy of all sub-lists, that will cause an `OutOfMemoryException` sometime.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There are no sublists though, this is just a string list. The only things that will be copied over to the new collection are the references to the strings stored in the original list. This shouldn't cause `OutOfMemoryException`, but is still unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Well for my test stand for *10 millions* (*10 times more* than you have) lines

```
  var data = Enumerable
   .Range(1, 10000000)
   .Select(item => "123456789 bla-bla-bla " + "MYNUMBER:" + item.ToString())
   .ToList();

  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();

  int result = ExtraktNumbers(data, 0, 10000000);

  sw.Stop();
```

I've got these results:

**2.78** seconds - your initial implementtation

Naive loop (**2.60** seconds):

```
private int ExtraktNumbers(List<string> myList, int start, int end) {
  int result = 0;

  for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
    if (myList[i].Contains("MYNUMBER:"))
      result += 1;

  return result;
}
```

PLinq (**1.72** seconds):

```
   private int ExtraktNumbers(List<string> myList, int start, int end) {
      return myList
        .AsParallel() // <- Do it in parallel
        .Skip(start - 1)
        .Take(end - start)
        .Where(x => x.Contains("MYNUMBER:"))
        .Count();
    }
```

Explicit parallel implementation (**1.66** seconds):

```
   private int ExtraktNumbers(List<string> myList, int start, int end) {
     long result = 0;

     Parallel.For(start, end, (i) => {
       if (myList[i].Contains("MYNUMBER:"))
         Interlocked.Increment(ref result);
     });

     return (int) result;
  }
```

I just cannot reproduce your **177** seconds

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comments I GUESS its because I don't just call the method once, but about 10k times that it increases that much (not sure why but I had managed to narrow the time increase down to the method itself).

Answer (score 0):

If you know from the beginning the intervals you want to consider, it's probably a good idea to loop the list once, as Dmytro and musefan proposed above, so I won't repeat the same idea again.

However I have a different suggestion for performance improvement. How do you create your list? Do you know the number of items in advance? Because for such a big list, you may gest a significant performance boost by using the `List<T>` [constructor that takes the initial capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx).